# How to update data from source table to Destination table with the help of third table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to update the data from table3 (Source table) to table1 (destination table) which doesn't have a direct relationship. I have to do it with the help of another mapping table, table2. Let me put down the table structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uscr3.png)

I am putting the logic here in the form of query. I know the syntax could be wrong. Please do suggest and give your advice. Thanks

Sample Query(to understand logic only):

```
UPDATE table1 destTab
SET (destTab.fname, destTab.lname) =
    (
        SELECT sourceTab.fname, sourceTab.lname
        FROM table3 sourceTab
        WHERE
            sourceTab.KEY = table2.KEY AND
            destTab.ID = table2.ID
    );
```

Can we achieve this requirement in a single query or do I need to write a script? Please do suggest and give your advice. Thanks

Comment: It would probably help to provide example data and expected output.

Comment: Plz find the sample snapshot of table structure in "enter image description here" hyperlink above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of temporary table's concept in oracle, which is a modular and easily understandable approach.

```
create global temporary table TEMP1(
ID VARCHAR2(50), KEY VARCHAR2(50))
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

create global temporary table TEMP2(
KEY VARCHAR2(50), FNAME VARCHAR2(100), LNAME VARCHAR2(100))
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

create global temporary table TEMP3(
ID VARCHAR2(50), FNAME VARCHAR2(100), LNAME VARCHAR2(100))
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;  

BEGIN
INSERT INTO TEMP1 (ID, KEY)
(select TABLE1.ID, TABLE2.KEY 
from TABLE1, TABLE2 
where TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID

INSERT INTO TEMP2(KEY, FINAME, LNAME)
(SELECT ID, FNAME,LNAME
FROM TABLE3
WHERE TABLE3.KEY IN (SELECT KEY FROM TEMP1)); 

INSERT INTO TEMP3(ID, FNAME, LNAME)
(SELECT TEMP1.ID, TEMP2.FNAME, T2.LNAME 
FROM TEMP1, TEMP2 
WHERE TEMP1.KEY = TEMP2.KEY);

UPDATE TABLE1
SET (TABLE1.FNAME, TABLE1.LNAME) = (SELECT FNAME, LNAME FROM TEMP3
WHERE TEMP3.ID = TABLE1.ID);
commit; 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a solution with like this =>

```
UPDATE 
    (SELECT table1.value as OLD, table2.CODE as NEW
     FROM table1
     INNER JOIN table2
     ON table1.value = table2.DESC
    ) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

(It depends if the inline view is considered updateable by Oracle).

So You can try this query:

```
 UPDATE
    (  select t1.fname_old
            , t1.lname_old
            , t3.fname_new
            , t3.lname_new
        from table1 t1
        join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        join table3 t3 on t2.key and t3.key 
    ) T
    SET T.fname_old = T.fname_new
      , T.lname_old = T.lname_new
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Definitely will try out!